# Ability to block add-in on Outlook desktop?

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

If the august community call it was shown that OfficeJS now supports blocking add-ins to load on specific environments, like Windows. But it appears only not to be available for Outlook. Is that indeed the case? Is there already a way to make sure and addin is not loaded in Outlook Desktop, but only on web and Mac?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're likely referring to the community call presentation about how you can add COM compatibility to your Office (web) Add-in by specifying the equivalent COM add-in in the Office Add-in manifest file. Currently this feature is only supported by Excel, Word, and PowerPoint, as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/make-office-add-in-compatible-with-existing-com-add-in).

However, please note that if you're looking for a way to make it so that your Office (web) Add-in will be available on web and Mac but not on Windows -- *even when there’s no equivalent COM add-in specified/present* -- this feature doesn’t enable that scenario. An equivalent COM add-in must be specified in the Office (web) Add-in manifest and that COM add-in must be present in order for the Office (web) Add-in to not be available for the user on Windows. Please see the docs I've linked to above for more details about this feature.